# Plotting multiple lines, in different colors, with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
   color  x   y
0    red  0   0
1    red  1   1
2    red  2   2
3    red  3   3
4    red  4   4
5    red  5   5
6    red  6   6
7    red  7   7
8    red  8   8
9    red  9   9
10  blue  0   0
11  blue  1   1
12  blue  2   4
13  blue  3   9
14  blue  4  16
15  blue  5  25
16  blue  6  36
17  blue  7  49
18  blue  8  64
19  blue  9  81
```

I ultimately want two lines, one blue, one red.  The red line should essentially be y=x and the blue line should be y=x^2

When I do the following:

```
df.plot(x='x', y='y')
```

The output is this:

[image]

Is there a way to make pandas know that there are two sets?  And group them accordingly.  I'd like to be able to specify the column `color` as the set differentiator

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Another simple way is to use the [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function to format the data.

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) to plot. Providing the colors in the `'color'` column exist in [matplotlib: List of named colors](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html), they can be passed to the `color` parameter.

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame([['red', 0, 0], ['red', 1, 1], ['red', 2, 2], ['red', 3, 3], ['red', 4, 4], ['red', 5, 5], ['red', 6, 6], ['red', 7, 7], ['red', 8, 8], ['red', 9, 9], ['blue', 0, 0], ['blue', 1, 1], ['blue', 2, 4], ['blue', 3, 9], ['blue', 4, 16], ['blue', 5, 25], ['blue', 6, 36], ['blue', 7, 49], ['blue', 8, 64], ['blue', 9, 81]],
                  columns=['color', 'x', 'y'])

# pivot the data into the correct shape
df = df.pivot(index='x', columns='color', values='y')

# display(df)
color  blue  red
x               
0         0    0
1         1    1
2         4    2
3         9    3
4        16    4
5        25    5
6        36    6
7        49    7
8        64    8
9        81    9

# plot the pivoted dataframe; if the column names aren't colors, remove color=df.columns
df.plot(color=df.columns, figsize=(5, 3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 90):

You could use `groupby` to split the DataFrame into subgroups according to the color:

```
for key, grp in df.groupby(['color']):
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for key, grp in df.groupby(['color']):
    ax = grp.plot(ax=ax, kind='line', x='x', y='y', c=key, label=key)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Comment: Couldn't make the solution work because my dataset wasn't colors and the parameter 'c' happens to be plot line color. In the OP's case it was fine but it will fail for everyone else. If you drop that parameter this fantastic solution will work on all other datasets as well.

Answer (score 31):

If you have `seaborn` installed, an easier method that does not require you to perform `pivot`:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='color')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the following code to plot multiple lines in different colors with pandas data frame.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

value1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] 
value2 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
value3 = [8, 9, 10, 15, 20]

results1 = DataFrame({'SAC': value1, 'TD3': value2, 'DDPG': value3})

results1.plot()
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.xlabel("Episode")
plt.ylabel("Rewards")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: you mean it is possible to transform the data frame so each column is for a different color

Answer (score 1):

The most general way is to plot the different color based on the `color` group. That is, we use `Dataframe.groupby` to group the colors and then plot the data on the relevant axes.

For example

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 1000
xy = np.random.rand(n,  2) + np.random.rand(n)[:, None]
color = np.random.randint(0, 3, size = n)
data = dict(x = xy[:, 0], y = xy[:, 1], color = color)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for labels, dfi in df.groupby("color"):
    dfi.plot(ax = ax, x = 'x', y = 'y', label = labels)
ax.legend(title = 'color')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -5):

You can use this code to get your desire output

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red','red','red','blue','blue','blue'], 'x': [0,1,2,3,4,5],'y': [0,1,2,9,16,25]})
print df

  color  x   y
0   red  0   0
1   red  1   1
2   red  2   2
3  blue  3   9
4  blue  4  16
5  blue  5  25
```

To plot graph

```
a = df.iloc[[i for i in xrange(0,len(df)) if df['x'][i]==df['y'][i]]].plot(x='x',y='y',color = 'red')
df.iloc[[i for i in xrange(0,len(df)) if df['y'][i]== df['x'][i]**2]].plot(x='x',y='y',color = 'blue',ax=a)

plt.show()
```

**Output**
[image: The output result will look like this]