# Legend on pandas plot of time series shows only "None"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, data-visualization

`data` is a pandas dataframe with a date-time-index on entries with multiple attributes. One of these attributes is called `STATUS`. I tried to create a plot of the number of entries per day, broken down by the `STATUS` attribute.

My first attempt using pandas.plot:

```
for status in data["STATUS"].unique():
    entries = data[data["STATUS"] == status]
    entries.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper("D")).size().plot(figsize=(16,4), legend=True)
```

The result:

[image]

How should I modify the code above so that the legend shows which status the curve belongs to?

Also, feel free to suggest a different approach to realizing such a visualization (group time series by time interval, count entries, and break down by attributes of the entries).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting multiple lines with pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233283/plotting-multiple-lines-with-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Which columns do you have? Maybe can you show a head and/or tail of your data?

Comment: What do you get as output for `data["STATUS"].unique()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that with below change to your code you will get what you want:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
for status in data["STATUS"].unique():
        entries = data[data["STATUS"] == status]
        dfPlot = pandas.DataFrame(entries.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper("D")).size())
        dfPlot.columns=[status]
        dfPlot.plot(ax=ax, figsize=(16,4), legend=True)
```

What happened is that the output for `size` function gives you a `Series` type with no name in its column. So creating a `Dataframe` from the `Series` and changing the column name does the trick.

Comment: Only that gives me one plot per iteration - need to figure out how to combine them into a single plot.