# Creating a graph for credits used by warehouse for a year using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to generate a graph, first i will be querying in the snowflake to fetch the data for the credits/resources consumed by warehouse over a year, i want to use this data to generate a line graph to see the trend of how a warehouse has consumed the costs/resources over past one year, for example if i have 5 warehouses, i want to see a line for each of them showing the trend for past one year..

i am new to this in graph thing in python and need help with this.

Regards
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this using `matplotlib`, `pandas` and the `snowflake-connector-python` Python 3.x modules installed.

You'll need to build a query that aggregates your warehouse metering history in the way you need, using the [`WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY` account usage view](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html) or equivalent. The example provided below uses a query that aggregates each month.

With the [query results in a Pandas DataFrame](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html#reading-data-from-a-snowflake-database-to-a-pandas-dataframe), you can then [use pivot to format the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233283/plotting-multiple-lines-with-pandas-dataframe) such that each warehouse series can appear as a line of its own.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from snowflake import connector

# Establish your connection here
con = connector.connect(…)

q = """
select
    warehouse_name as warehouse,
    date_trunc('month', end_time)::date in_month,
    sum(credits_used) credits
from snowflake.account_usage.warehouse_metering_history
where warehouse_id != 0
group by warehouse, in_month
order by warehouse, in_month;
"""

df = con.cursor().execute(q).fetch_pandas_all()

# Explicitly specify datatypes for all columns so they behave well
df['IN_MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['IN_MONTH'])
tdf = df.astype({'WAREHOUSE': 'string', 'CREDITS': 'float'})

pdf = tdf.pivot(index='IN_MONTH', columns='WAREHOUSE', values='CREDITS')
pdf.plot()

plt.show()
```

This yields:

[image: matplotlib chart figure with a blue and yellow line depicting different warehouse costs]

P.s. You can alternatively try the [native Snowsight features in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-visualizations.html) to plot interactive charts right from its SQL editor interface:

[image: snowsight chart result view with columns configured to show multiple series of data as interactive lines]

Comment: Thanks for your help.. i will try this with python.. In snow sight .. i kind of already did it.. l like this new snow sight.. it saves time..

Comment: Thanks You, i was able to create the graph with slight changes in the code mentioned above.. Thank You for the help